# Import vlc.py in to python directory (sys.path) in raspberry pi

Tags: python, vlc, raspberry-pi2

I am trying to import the vlc module in to python directory in raspberry pi, but error comes which says No module named VLC. can anyone tell me the way to import vlc module in python.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Did you install [`python-vlc`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-vlc)?

Comment: No i didn't install python-vlc. can you tell me the steps to install it? am new to both python and raspberry pi.

Comment: Install from the linked page https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-vlc. You can use `pip` or download and install manually.

Comment: Thanks for your help. i'll do it and let you know the results :)

Comment: I have downloaded the python-vlc tar file and extract it. i don't know how to install and import it in to python?

Comment: Did you read the `README` file? However, the easiest way is to use `pip` which is probably already installed: `pip install python-vlc` as root user. If it's not installed, you could try here https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/

Comment: Finally, I managed to import vlc module. Thanks for that. But now i got struck with some other error which is (No module named Pathlib). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first have to install [python-vlc](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-vlc) on the raspberry (as mentioned in the comments) with pip

```
sudo pip install python-vlc
```

Then you can import the python module

```
import vlc
```

Comment: @SivamNatesan Good to hear. If you think the answer was usefull, an upvote/accept would be nice

Comment: Finally, I managed to import vlc module. Thanks for that. But now i got struck with some other error which is (No module named Pathlib). I am using python 2.7. Any suggestions?  @salomonderossi

Comment: @SivamNatesan `sudo pip install pathlib`?